# Создание dll из С++ кода, использующего другую dll (в частности, OpenCV) и вызов ее из C#-кода

Tags: c#, c++, dll, opencv

Пытаюсь создать dll из С++-кода средствами VS2015, а затем вызвать эти функции из C#-кода.

Простые функции, содержащие только примитивы языка, вызываются без проблем. Однако, в дальнейшем нужно будет подключать dll, в коде которых содержится OpenCV.

Ниже выложены примеры кода.

DllTest.cpp

```
// DllTest.cpp
#include "DllTest.h"

int StringSize(const char *str)
{
  return strlen(str);
}

double GetMatrixElement()
{
  cv::Mat a; // Матрица из OpenCV. Без этой строки все работает.

  return 1.0;
}
```

DllTest.h

```
// DllTest.h
#pragma once

#ifdef OPENCV_DLL_TEST_EXPORTS
#define  OPENCV_DLL_TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define  OPENCV_DLL_TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" OPENCV_DLL_TEST_API int StringSize(const char *str);

extern "C" OPENCV_DLL_TEST_API double GetMatrixElement();
```

ClientForm.cs

```
namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [DllImport("Host.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "StringSize")]
        public static extern int StringSize(string str);

        [DllImport("Host.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "GetMatrixElement")]
        public static extern double GetMatrixElement();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetMatrixElement());
            Console.WriteLine(StringSize("Hellooo"));
        }
    }
}
```

В результате получаю исключение на функции `GetMatrixElement()`:

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.DllNotFoundException" в Client.exe

Дополнительные сведения: Unable to load DLL 'Host.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Подскажите, как быть в этом случае. Спасибо.

Comment: А из С++ эту библиотеку можно использовать?

Comment: Весь проект написан на C#, к сожалению. Сам я пишу на C++, но коллеги попросили сделать dll. Или вы имеете в виду, можно ли в принципе использовать это, не будет ли проблем таких же?

Comment: Да, можно ли в принципе использовать это, не будет ли проблем таких же

Comment: Попробую это сделать.

Comment: В общем, я попробовал использовать эту dll из С++-кода, когда просто создавал `cv::Mat a`, но видимо компилятор просто не создал эту переменную, так как когда я попытался ее заполнить, вылезло исключение. Попробовал просто выделить память оператором new - то же самое. Какая-то проблема выделения динам. памяти при использовани dll.

Comment: Исправил ошибку с исключением, теперь могу создавать динамические типы, однако, как только я добавляю OpenCV, функция LoadLibrary возвращает нулевой указатель. Opencv-шную dll так же клал в папку проекта с экзешником.